# Why DrupalWebTestCase processing took so long?

Tags: 7, testing

I want to create a test that uses the database, so I must use the `DrupaWebTestCase` class.

I create the following test class with this simple test:

```
class MyModuleTest extends DrupalWebTestCase {  
  /**
   * Implements getInfo().
   */
  public static function getInfo() {
    return array (
      // Info stuff
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp('my_module');
  }

  public function testHelloWorld() {
    $this->assertEqual(t('Hello World'), 'Hello World');
  } 
}
```

And this **SINGLE** test is taking around 1 minute every time. Why is that long?

I know Drupal must bootstrap, but it's annoying.

What I am doing wrong here?

I am launching the test from admin/config/development/testing.

I tried it on a fresh Drupal 7 installation: It took the same time.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times already, ave a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30947/using-drupalwebtestcase-any-trick-to-prevent-it-from-running-from-scratch-each?rq=1 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30947/using-drupalwebtestcase-any-trick-to-prevent-it-from-running-from-scratch-each?rq=1, that should help to speed up your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 minute is not the time took from Drupal from executing `MyModuleTest::testHelloWorld()`; it's the time took to create the test environment, execute the tests, and delete the test environment, including the database tables, and the files created during the test.

When [DrupalWebTestCase::setUp()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3asetUp/7) is executed, a temporary Drupal installation is created right for the time to execute the test; after the test is terminated, the Drupal installation is deleted. This means, for example that at least the Node, User, and the System modules create (and then delete) their own database tables; the list of installed modules contains all the Drupal core modules that are necessary to run Drupal, and all the modules the test declares as dependency.

The only ways to speed up the execution would be:

- Use a different database engine for the tests. This would be possible by calling [db_set_active()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) in `MyModuleTest::setUp()`, before calling `parent::setUp()`. It requires the settings.php file contains the definition for the connection to use during the tests.
- Instead of creating the single database tables, they are created from a backup file. This would require to hack the way the test environment is created. By default, any required module is asked to create its own database table; `MyModuleTest::setUp()` should handle the initialisation of the test environment without calling `parent::setUp()`.
  The bigger issue with this approach is that the backup needs to contain the database tables updated for the latest versions of the modules; this is probably easier to do for Drupal core modules. The tests are speeded-up when they are executed frequently enough; if the test are executed rarely, then there isn't any performance improvement.

You can look at the [Project Issue File Review](http://drupal.org/project/project_issue_file_review) module (a.k.a PIFR), which is the module running the server used to test Drupal core patches, and the patches submitted for Drupal.org projects with enabled tests.

Comment: I understand, so it is not possible to speed up this?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info. I hope this will be improvement in future, now it's major pain in the ass for me

Comment: Anyway I will to test Drupal with raw PHPUnit

Answer (score 2):

I will preface this answer with the fact I'm still very new to automated testing.

DrupalWebTestCase could surely run faster, though I doubt you'll ever match the speed of [PHPUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit).  The only way I can think to reduce the overall time spent testing your code would be to use functional/implementation tests (DrupalWebTestCase) as infrequently as possible.

Enter [DrupalUnitTestCase](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/class/DrupalUnitTestCase/7).

One trick I use is to seperate out DB interaction in my modules as much as possible so I can use serialized input for quick unit testing. Of course this doesn't always make sense, nor will it work under every circumstance but it can help speedup the time your tests take to run so you can test early and test often.

Consider the following non-working and untested code:

**Before**

```
//Cannot test with DrupalUnitTestCase due to DB interaction.
function module_my_custom_function($uid) {
  $result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created 
  FROM {node} n 
  WHERE n.uid = :uid', array (':uid' => $uid));

  //Do stuff to $result here...

  return $whatever;
}
```

**After**

```
//Cannot test with DrupalUnitTestCase due to DB interaction.
function module_my_custom_function_query($uid) {
  return db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created 
  FROM {node} n 
  WHERE n.uid = :uid', array (':uid' => $uid));
}

//Can test with DrupalUnitTestCase using serialized 'known to be good' input.
function module_my_custom_function($db_result) {

  //Do stuff to $db_result here...

  return $whatever;
}
```

Now I can snag known good values from `module_my_custom_function_query()` and manually insert it into my tests setUp() method using PHP's [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)() function.

```
$insert_in_unit_test_setup = serialize(module_my_custom_function_query(1));
```

I know many of you cringed at what I just did, but this has saved me tons of time during testing.

```
class MyModuleTest extends DrupalUnitTestCase {  

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array (
      // Info stuff
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    //Unserialize your manually saved results here to avoid DB queries for quick testing.
    $this->saved_db_results = unserialize('a:3:{i:1;s:3:"One";i:2;s:3:"Two";i:3;s:5:"Three";}'); 
    parent::setUp('my_module');
  }

  public function testMyFunction() {
    $db_results = $this->saved_db_results;
    $result = module_my_custom_function($db_results);
    $expected = 'Whatever';
    $message = 'A message about the test...';
    $this->assertIdentical($result, $expected, $message);
  } 
}
```

You can't completely avoid Functional tests, but you can at least reduce the number of times you have to run them during active development saving you time in the long run.

Some additional information on [Drupals implementation](http://drupal.org/project/simpletest) of the [Simpletest framework](http://simpletest.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: The OP said, "I want to create a test that uses the database." What he is showing is not the test he will need to run, but a simple test the OP noticed to take too long, even if it doesn't do much.

Comment: Updated my answer to try and better address original question taking in account the followup 'raw PHPUnit' comment. :)  I definitely missed the DB requirement on the first line.